# How to use OpenShift environment variables to configure a MySQL database

Tags: java, spring-boot, openshift, jhipster

So I generated an application with JHipster.

Locally, I would just modify the database info in the application-dev.yml/application-prod.yml and everything works fine.

Now I want to deploy my application on OpenShift. I tried putting the environment variable names in the application-xxx.yml but it returned null. So I modified the `DatabaseConfiguration.java` to skip reading the info from the .yml file and read them directly from the environment variables.

```
if(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST") != null && System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT") != null){
    config.addDataSourceProperty("url", "jdbc:mysql://"+System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST")+":"+System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT")+"/zetravelcloud?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8");
}
if (System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME") != null) {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
} else {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null user
}
System.out.println(System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
if (System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD") != null) {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
} else {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null password
}
```

instead of

```
config.addDataSourceProperty("url", dataSourceProperties.getUrl());
if (dataSourceProperties.getUsername() != null) {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", dataSourceProperties.getUsername());
} else {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("user", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null user
}
if (dataSourceProperties.getPassword() != null) {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", dataSourceProperties.getPassword());
} else {
    config.addDataSourceProperty("password", ""); // HikariCP doesn't allow null password
}
```

**Now the question is: How to correctly use the OpenShift environment variables in my configuration class to successfully connect to the database?**

Bonus question: What is a better way to solve this, I don't feel it's right to put the variable names in the `DatabaseConfiguration` class?

Comment: Using ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST} syntax in application.yml is the way to do it and it should work. How did you try?

Comment: Oh thanks apparently I had to restart my windows machine for it to work. I rolled back my class modifications and committed the new WAR. I'm gonna look into the openshift logs to see what the errors are. If you post this comment as an answer I would happily accept it as the correct one. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST} syntax in application.yml is the way to do it and it should work.